# Return position of a node in the linked list, recursive approach

Tags: java, recursion, linked-list

So, I am trying to solve a problem where I am supposed to write a recursive method to search for a node in the linked list, and return it's index (indexing from 0). If the node doesn't exist, I need to return -1. This is how far I got implementing the logic. It works fine for all test cases I suppose, except for one, when the node is not in the linked list, it returns last index of the linked list in that case.

This is my logic.

```
public static int indexOfNRec(LinkedListNode<Integer> head, int n) {
    if(head==null)
        return -1;
    if(head.data==n)    
        return 0;
    int count=1;
    return count+indexOfNRec(head.next,n);
}
```

This is the code for the LinkedListNode

```
class LinkedListNode<T> {
T data;
LinkedListNode<T> next;

public Node(T data) 
    this.data = data;
}
```

I understand why my logic fails, but I am not able to solve the issue. I'm sorry to ask such a basic question, I'm poor with recursion.

Comment: How do you call your indexOfNRec method?

Comment: Check the value of indexOfNRec(head.next,n). If it's -1, you shouldn't increment it. You should return -1 instead.

Comment: If `indexOfNRec(head.next,n)` returns -1, then you shouldn't return `count+indexOfNRec(head.next,n)`. Instead, you should return -1.

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks mate!!! :) Forgot that I could have an if-else hehe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
int returnValue = indexOfNRec(head.next,n);
return (returnValue ==  -1) ? -1: returnValue;
```

(using 
`if (indexOfNRec(head.next,n).....`
`return count+indexOfNRec(head.next,n);` 

is inefficient because it doubles the number of times you run the recursion)

Answer (score 3):

i took a helper function to solve the problem,

```
public static int helper(LinkedListNode<Integer> head, int n,int pos)
{   
    if(head==null)
      return -1;

    if(head.data==n)
    {
        return pos;
    }

    int ans=helper(head.next,n,pos+1);
    return ans;
}


public static int indexOfNRec(LinkedListNode<Integer> head, int n) {


  return helper(head,n,0);                                                

}
```

it works in all test cases.

Answer (score 2):

In Python v2.5 >

```
def searchRecursive(head, n):
    if head is None:
        return -1
    if head.data == n:
        return 0
    index = searchRecursive(head.next, n)
    return (1 + index) if index != -1 else -1
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my Code. I am taking starting index as 0.

Base Case: If the head is null that means if the node is not found and it returns -1 and then while doing the calculation I check if the return is -1 then return -1 to decrease the count.

Other Cases: Increase the value by 1 as you traverse and return 0 if the node is found.

```
public static int indexOfNRec(LinkedListNode<Integer> head, int n) {

    if(head==null)
        return -1;

    else
    {
        if(head.data!=n)
        {   
            int k = indexOfNRec(head.next, n);

            if(k!=-1)
                return k+1;

            else
                return -1;
        }
        else
            return 0;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def findnodeRE(head,i):
if head==None :
    return -1
if head.data==i:
    return 0
head=findnodeRE(head.next,i)
if head!=-1:
    return 1+head
else:
    -1
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't explain how it solves the problem. Please edit your answer to explain what this code does and how it improves on the existing answer this old questino already has, so that it is useful to other users with similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

**In Python 3.8**

```
def findNodeRec(head, n):
    # Your code goes here
    if head is None:
        return -1
    if head.data == n:
        return 0
    count = findNodeRec(head.next, n)
    if count!=-1:
        return 1+count
    else:
        return -1
```

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged. Please provide a summary of how your answer solves the problem and why it may be preferable to the other answers already provided.

Answer (score 0):

This should be the function in c++ to return the position of the node in the linked list.

```
    int findNodeRecursive(Node *head, int n)
    {
          int smallAns;
          if(head == NULL){
             return -1;
          }
          if(head -> data == n) {
             return 0;
          } 

          if(head -> data != n){
             smallAns = findNodeRecursive(head -> next, n);
    
              if(smallAns != -1){
                  return smallAns + 1;
              }
              else{
                  return -1;
              }
          }
    }
```